# Check if set of elements is present in other set of elements with lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, lodash

field `game_options` has some parameters set
I need to look if requested options are the same as `game_options`

```
game_options = ['ps2', 'pc']
request = ['ps2', 'pc', 'xbox']
```

this combination should return false
but this: true:

```
game_options = ['ps2', 'pc', 'xbox']
request = ['ps2', 'pc']
```

i have done this with lodash, but dont sure if it is the right way:

```
_ = require 'lodash'
hasAllRequestedOptions - (options, request) ->
  return true if _.intersection(game_options, request).length is request.length
  return false
```

Comment: I'd use `return !_.difference(request, game_options).length`

Comment: @georg it returns ['xbox'] for second

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [difference](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) function to achieve that:

```
game_options = ['ps2', 'pc'];
request = ['ps2', 'pc', 'xbox'];

console.log(_.difference(game_options, request).length > 0);

game_options = ['ps2', 'pc', 'xbox'];
request = ['ps2', 'pc'];

console.log(_.difference(game_options, request).length > 0);
```

Comment: what if request = ['pc'] , game_options = ['pc'] @JesusRT

Answer (score 0):

```
var isPresented = _.intersection(game_options, request).length === request.length
```